# Struggling Python Newb. Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: python

Simple RPS program. Program is now functioning except for the prompt to play again, but then it throws errors after that. These are the errors I'm getting back:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()
   File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 29, in <module>
    play_game()
   File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 58, in <module>
    winner=determine_the_winner(computer_choice,player_choice)
   File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 102, in <module>
    return winner
   builtins.NameError: name 'winner' is not defined
```

Code:

```
#Imports the random module
import random

#Displays the welcome message, uses a while loop to determine if the
#player wishes to continue
def main():
#Displays the welcome message
print("Welcome to the most intense, and exciting game of rock, paper,\
scissors you have ever played.  People with heart conditions, small\
children, and the elderly should proceed with caution!!!!")

#create a variable for the control loop
keep_going = "y"

#Play the game and determine whether or not the player wishes to continue
while keep_going == "y" or keep_going == "Y":

    #use a function to play the game
    play_game()

    #Determine if they wish to play again
    keep_going = input("Do you wish to play again?(enter y to continue):")

#play_game function will call a function to get a randomly generated number
#for the computers choice. Call a function to get and return the players   choice.
#Use print statements to display the computers choice. Call a function to 
#determine the winner

def play_game():

#call a function to generate the computers choice
computer_choice=get_computer_choice()

#call a function to get the players choice
player_choice=get_players_choice()

#Print statements to display the computers choice
if computer==1:
    print("The almighty computer has chosen ROCK!!!")
elif computer==2:
    print("The almighty computer has chosen PAPER!!!")
elif computer==3:
    print("The almighty computer has chosen SCISSORS!!!")
else:
    print("Stupid computer. The choices are 1,2,3")

#call a function to determine the winner
winner=determine_the_winner(computer_choice,player_choice)


#Generate a random integer for the omputers choice and return that
#Value
def get_computer_choice():
computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
return computer_choice

#Use an input statement to get the players choice, use a while statement
#to determine whether the choice is valid. Return the value.

def get_players_choice():
print("Select a choice: \n (1):Rock \n (2): Paper \n (3):Scissors")
player_choice=input("Please enter a menu selection:")
while player_choice >3 or player_choice < 1:
    print("ERROR!!! PLease make a valid menu selection!!!")
    player_choice = int(input("Enter a correct selection please:"))
return player_choice

#Use if ,elif,else statements to detrmine the winner and return the value

def determine_the_winner(computer_choice,player_choice):
if player_choice ==1:
    print("You have chosen Rock!")
    if computer_choice ==1:
        print("Computer has chosen rock as well. TIE!")
        return winner
    elif computer_choice ==2:
        print("The computer has chosen paper. Paper covers rock! You LOSE!")
        return winner
    else:
        print("The computer has cosen scissors. Rock breaks Scissors. You WIN!!!")
        return winner
elif player_choice == 2:
    print("You have chosen Paper.")
    if computer_choice==1:
        print("The computer has chosen Rock! Paper covers Rock. You Win!!!")
        return winner
    elif computer_choice == 2:
        print("The computer has chosen Paper as well. TIE!!!")
        return winner
    else:
        print("The computer has chosen Scissors. Scissors cut Paper! You LOSE!!!!")
        return winner

else:
    print("You have chosen Scissors!")
    if computer_choice ==1:
        print("The computer has chosen Rock. Rock breaks Scissors! You LOSE!!!")
        return winner

    elif computer_choice == 2:
        print("The computer has chosen Paper. Scissors cut Paper! You WIN!!!")
        return winner
    else:
        print("The computer has chosen Scissors as well. TIE!!!")
        return winner

main()
```

Any and all helpful input is welcomed!

Comment: What *"errors"*?! Please give a [mcve] and tell us what the *actual problem is*.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()
  File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 29, in <module>
    play_game()
  File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 45, in <module>
    player_choice=get_players_choice()
  File "f:\programming class\homework\DyerS#6.py", line 73, in <module>
    while player_choice >3 or player_choice < 1:
builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: post it in your question and not as a comment

Comment: [**Edit the question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33260993/edit), you donut. Or just read and then search for that error message, which tells you exactly what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks for your help and insight!

Answer (score 1):

```
player_choice=input("Please enter a menu selection:")
while player_choice >3 or player_choice < 1:
```

In Python 3.X, `input` returns a string, and you can't compare a string to an integer. Convert the value to int before assigning.

```
player_choice=int(input("Please enter a menu selection:"))
while player_choice >3 or player_choice < 1:
```

Comment: Thanks bud. This was helpful. The game now works but I am still  getting errors back after it completes.